# Firebase cloud function performance profiler

Tags: node.js, firebase, performance, google-cloud-functions, profiling

Is it possible to profile a Firebase cloud function with tools like [ClinicJs](https://clinicjs.org/) or the builtin [V8 profiler](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/), both locally or remote (deployed)?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no support in Cloud Functions for profiling tools with deployed functions.

You could certainly try to set up something for local profiling.  I suggest giving it a shot, and if it doesn't work, post an explanation of what you've done and how it's not working the way you expect.